# Azure portal crashes after specific file uploaded to assets in mediaservice

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azureportal

After I upload another file to Assets in Media Service of azure portal  this function become completely broken. This section shows me an error and does work completely.

This error does not depend on browser I use and it is not a problem of browser cache.

Console logs - http://static.realgrad.ru/portal.azure.com-1487781825223.log.txt

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: just do not use azure portal to upload your media. There are SDKs for that. There is even [Media Services Explorer Tool](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer). Do not abuse the portal for this stuff.

Comment: I do use azure SDK. Then I still prefer to look in portal sometimes.